# phpcassa throws warning on LongType and dateOf(TimeUUIDType)

Tags: cassandra, phpcassa

I have the following table in cassandra;

```
CREATE TABLE reports (
  c_date text,
  c_n int,
  c_id timeuuid,
  report_id bigint,
  report text,
  PRIMARY KEY ((c_date, c_n), c_id)
)
```

`c_date` is for querying reports by date.

`c_n` is the number of nodes to prevent hotspots(number of nodes to distribute data evenly).

`c_id` is the inserted timeuuid.

My select query (cql 3) is the following;

```
select report, dateOf(c_id), report_id 
from keyspace.reports 
where c_date = '2013-08-02' and 
      c_n = 1 and 
      c_id > minTimeuuid('2013-08-02 02:52:10-0400');
```

I have successfully get the result set;
However, when I use `cql_get_rows()` function implemented on another example ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16139362/cassandra-is-not-retrieving-the-correct-integer-value)),

the timestamp (dateOf(id)) cannot be parsed correctly and bigint fields yield the following warning;

```
PHP Warning:  unpack(): Type N: not enough input, need 4, have 0 
in /home/arascan/my-project/tools/vendor/phpcassa/lib/phpcassa/Schema/DataType/LongType.php on line 47
```

The returned data from `cql_get_rows()` is the following;

```
  [0] => Array
        (
            [reportid] => 281474976712782
            [report]   => some_report
            [dateOf(c_id)] => d:1375426331.32100009918212890625;
        )
```

How can I prevent this function throw warning and get the timestamp in date format? 
(Please don't suggest @ usage)